# RESTEasy POST with ajax cors error in different domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, cors, resteasy

Using REStEasy I had created POST service and it is working in chrome plugin.
But using ajax I am not able to call the service.
Getting the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/RESTEasyJSONExample/rest/jsonServices/send. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
```

this is happening as the client and server urls are different,
but I want that server should allow request from any url. So I need to implement CORS in rest api. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class provided by RESTEasy to deal with CORS. The class is [CorsFilter.java](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/CorsFilter.java) and must be used as a request filter. You need to create your own class extending the RESTEasy class and annotating your class with `@Provider`.